# Regex for 9 unique digits separated by a space?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a piece of validation code for an input of numbers. The numbers have to contain 0 to 8. The order does not matter, but the digits cannot be repeated.

E.g. 1 4 7 8 0 2 5 3 6 //valid
     1 1 3 6 3 8 0 5 4 //invalid as 1 is repeated

I have a regex so far that takes in 9 unique digits:

```
 String pattern = "^(?!.*(.).*\\1)\\d{9}";
```

E.g. 123456780 //valid

112345678 //invalid as 1 is repeated

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 //invalid

All I need is to add the bit where it takes in the digits separated by a space!

Thanks.

Comment: Add to a `Set`, check the length is 9.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for check the repeting. Use the regex to check for the numbers, split then to array, convert it to a set, the repeting will merge, check the length

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doesn't work unfortunately. Just returns invalid input.

Comment: This is a great example of when **not** to use regex, as in every position in the input, what is valid depends on every single character preceding it.

Comment: @biziclop That is opinion-based. Java regex can cope with this problem, see [Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55395190/3832970). The only check that is needed is to make sure there are no repeated digits in the string, which is a child's play  for a lookahead. One just needs to write it correctly.

Comment: Is it child's play to read it though? And strictly speaking lookahead is an abuse of regex, as it makes the expression...well, not regular. (Of course it's opinion-based, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. Technically every finite language is regular. The question is whether it's a good idea to model it as such.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm sure you can model even the 8 Queens puzzle in Regexp, the question is: is it worth it, or there is a better solution for that specific problem?

Comment: @gaborsch A regex can be used outside of code, in settings/configs without having to mess with the code, and there are other practical application of *regex* solution. A lot of Java regex questions are not about using the pattern inside Java code, but inside Java based apps, and for those users a Java code answer will be of no use. A better solution for one scenario does not mean it is better for another. Here, the question is about a regex, so the regex answer is the best.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree that the question was about a regexp, that's why I'm not answering, because I'd solve the problem differently. It is also true that it _can_ be solved outside of the Java context, but in practice it _is_ solved within a Java context. That's true, that it is a one-liner solution, but as biziclop pointed out, it is a write-only code, and you'd need 20 lines of comment to document it for your successor. IMHO it would be better to write 10 lines of code, then 5 lines to document - and it would be thousand times more readable.

Comment: @gaborsch It all depends where the regex will be used. *A better solution for one scenario does not mean it is better for another.* Please stop this off-topic, our comments must be cleaned up.

Answer (score 3):

This is really abuse of regex :D but

```
^(?!.*(\d).*\1)(?:[0-8] ){8}[0-8]$
```

should do it. Make sure only digits are taken into consideration in the part where you disallow repetition; then you can have eight digit-space pairs followed by a digit at the end (with correct digits).

Comment: Regex.java:10: error: illegal escape character
                String pattern = "^(?!.*(\d).*\1)(?:\d ){8}\d$";
                                          ^
Regex.java:10: error: illegal escape character
                String pattern = "^(?!.*(\d).*\1)(?:\d ){8}\d$";
                                                     ^
Regex.java:10: error: illegal escape character
                String pattern = "^(?!.*(\d).*\1)(?:\d ){8}\d$";

Comment: That's regex; I leave it up to you to make sure Java String literal is correct (i.e. you need to double up the backslashes for Java to understand it correctly).

Comment: Instead of `\d` you should use `[0-8]` as OP said he wants to have the digits from 0 to 8 (so he is excluding the 9).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Oh, I missed they wrote that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need a regex for this. Consider using a `Set`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
int count = 0;
while (count < 9) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 8) {
        set.add(num);
    }
    count++;
}

System.out.println(set.size() == 9);
```

Or if your input comes in one go:

```
String[] nums = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
for (String num : nums) {
    set.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
}
```

You'll have to consider checking for invalid input. Or you could check the `nums` is 9 first before adding to set and return `false` then straight away.